# Resolve UITapGestureRecognizer and UILongPressGestureRecognizer simultaneously and fire UIGestureRecognizer.State.began on finger touch down

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer, uilongpressgesturerecogni

First of all, none of the already answered questions didn't help me

1. [Swift: Long Press Gesture Recognizer - Detect taps and Long Press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058082/swift-long-press-gesture-recognizer-detect-taps-and-long-press)
2. [Using tap gesture and long press at the same time in Table View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53768638/using-tap-gesture-and-long-press-at-the-same-time-in-table-view)
3. [Long Press Gesture Recognizer Only Fired When Finger is Lifted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382052/long-press-gesture-recognizer-only-fired-when-finger-is-lifted)
4. And so on

The code working almost fine except one thing: the long press gesture only called when I lift my finger up from the screen. But I need to get behaviour like in Instagram Stories (when you can switch between stories and hold your finger to pause pause some story).

**My question is more about how to force UILongPressGesture to fire when user touch finger down, but not up.**

Here's my code:

```
private func setupTapGestures() {
    tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    tapRecognizer?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTapGesture(_:)))
    tapRecognizer?.delegate = self
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer!)

    longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()
    longPressRecognizer?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLongPressGesture(_:)))
    longPressRecognizer?.minimumPressDuration = 0.1
    longPressRecognizer?.delegate = self
    view.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer!)
}

@objc func handleTapGesture(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let width = view.frame.width
    let point = gestureRecognizer.location(in: view)
    viewModel?.tapAction(viewWidth: width, tapPoint: point)
    Swift.print("Tap gesture")
}

@objc func handleLongPressGesture(_ gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began {
        Swift.print("Began")
    } else if gestureRecognizer.state == .ended {
        Swift.print("Ended")
    }
}
```

**UIGestureRecognizerDelegate**:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRequireFailureOf otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    // Don't recognize a single tap until a long-press fails
    if gestureRecognizer == tapRecognizer && otherGestureRecognizer == longPressRecognizer {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

[shouldRequireFailureOf docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/coordinating_multiple_gesture_recognizers/preferring_one_gesture_over_another)

Any suggestions or ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if your implementation of `shouldRequireFailureOf` is causing an issue?

This works just fine for me (note: I used `.minimumPressDuration = 0.25` because it's a little difficult to tap in under 0.1 seconds):

```
class GestureTestViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupTapGestures()
    }

    private func setupTapGestures() -> Void {

        let singleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTapGesture(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(singleTapGesture)

        let longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongPressGesture(_:)))
        longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.25
        view.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)

    }

    @objc func handleLongPressGesture(_ gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
        if gesture.state == .began {
            print("Did Long Press (began)")
        }
        if gesture.state == .ended {
            print("Did Long Press (ended)")
        }
    }

    @objc func handleTapGesture(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
        print("Did Single Tap")
    }

}
```

When I **tap**, I get *"Did Single Tap"* in the debug console.

When I **tap and hold**, I quickly get *"Did Long Press (began)"*, and on finger-lift I get *"Did Long Press (ended)"*

Comment: Hm, your code works in the playground, but not in my project. Will look into, thanks!

Comment: Ok for anyone who may get the same unexpected behavior, I've been using custom transitioning UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, so when I disable it, everything works fine.